# Goole My Business API: Get Location Products

Tags: google-my-business-api

I am working with the Google My Business API: https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest

I need to get the Locations Products. I tried with Location LocalPost, but the Product type is not available.

Any help on this?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the Merchant Center product feed yet? https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/7439058

Comment: Nop, Thanks @vpriesner I will research it